# Public dataset for OLAP design

Tags: dataset, olap

I need a complex (in some degree) public dataset for OLAP kind of analysis and reports. Foodmart, AdventureWorks and Steel-Wheels which comes with BI products are focused primary on a single domain - retail sale, and the datasets I have worked with in my employment
also are not much different then those.

I am in search for some interesting and complex dataset (from health sector, etc) having adequate dimension and facts for challenging OLAP design.

There are a lot of public dataset available, in AWS, and in various links provided in this very site (stackoverflow) but I find none of them to be applicable for OLAP design but for data mining.

Can anyone please help me to point out or share some datasets as I have mentioned.

Regards

Comment: Have you found anything in this regard?  It would be fantastic if there was a repository of reference schema's.

Comment: Hi, hope it's not a problem that I'm opening this issue again so many years later... I feel to be stuck in the same situation. Have any of you managed to find a solution?